# Error message when deploying app to Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

When deploying my app `(shinyapps::deployApp('path/to/your/app')`, I get the following error message:

```
error: Parsing manifest
################################## Begin Log ################################## 
################################### End Log ################################### 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 30191454 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unsupported locale: it_NA.UTF-8
```

It looks like it's got to do with encoding, as I am from Italy. However I didn't use any strange characters.

I tried "Save with encoding">UTF-8. I tried deploying it but I got the same error message.

It works fine when hosted locally.

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Probability Calculator"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Calculate posterior probability of an outcome"),


      numericInput("nofs", 
                   label = "Number of successes",
                   value=1),

      numericInput("notr", 
                   label = "Number of trials",
                   value=1),

      sliderInput("range", 
                  label = "Confidence Interval",
                  min = 0, max = 1, value = c(0, 1))


    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("Calculator")
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$Calculator <- renderText({
  x=1:10000000 
  denominator<-dbinom(input$nofs, size=input$notr, prob=(x/10000000))
  sommadenominator=sum(denominator)
  h1=(input$range[1]*10000000):(input$range[2]*10000000) 
  numerator<-dbinom(input$nofs, size=input$notr, prob=(h1/10000000)) 

  sommanumerator=sum(numerator)

  sommanumerator/sommadenominator
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was solved thanks to Andy Kipp on  [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/vy2TGpHAgm8) by fixing the shinyapps package. I had to redownload it and redeploy the app. 
Specifically: Please update your shinyapps package by doing:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')
```

Then try this:

```
options(shinyapps.locale.cache=FALSE)
shinyapps:::systemLocale()
```

And then try `deployApp()`, after making sure you've load the `shinyapps` library that you've just installed `library(shinyapps)`

Comment: this package is now depreciated and no longer works

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error. First I tried updating the shiny apps package using Davide's answer but still received the error. I ended up deleted the Icon file that was auto-generated in my directory and then I was able to publish. I did it as a last resort though, since I'm not sure what the Icon file does and couldn't find any references about it.