# shinyapps deployment; Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task

Tags: r, locale, rstudio, shiny

Smashing my head against a brick wall trying to deploy a shiny app on a new laptop. I am testing things out with the template app in Rstudio (File|New Project|New Directory|Shiny Web Application for the Old Faithful Geyser Data (so very simple and requires no additional packages).

I have tried on different networks, updated RStudio (to 0.99.896) and R (to 3.2.5). Persistently get this message...

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 96234...DONE
Deploying bundle: 427331 for application: 96234 ...
Waiting for task: 180491371
  building: Building image: 420289
  building: Building package: digest
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 180491373 error: Unhandled Exception: HTTP 599: Connection closed
Execution halted
```

Following suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30033208/513463) I tried to change my adminstrative language to US English (through the control panel in Windows). However, despite uninstalling/reinstalling R and Rstudio, restatrting the computor, R seems to be fixed on `English_United Kingdom`...

```
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rsconnect_0.4.2.2 tools_3.2.5       RCurl_1.95-4.8    RJSONIO_1.3-0    
[5] digest_0.6.9      bitops_1.0-6
```

I then tried to set the locale in R directly:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

which works but `shinyapps:::systemLocale` seems unmoved...

```
> options(shinyapps.locale.cache=FALSE)
> 
> shinyapps:::systemLocale()
Detecting system locale ... en_GB
[1] "en_GB"
```

and I still cannot get the app deployed to shinyapps.io. I have a few students with the same problems when trying to deploy on the shinyapps site with their PCs. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is due the newest version of R. 
R 3.2.5 is not supported right now. You have to downgrade your version.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/5WIEuHfwpiU 
Check this link

Comment: Thanks. I will try again next week, and give you the answer accept, if all works. upvotes for now.

Comment: Problem disappeared with R 3.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was a file "**manifest.json**". Delete this file and re-publish the application.

I just worked fine both on 3.5 and 3.4

The versions of r and rshiny are mentioned in this json file.

So: I don't think it is a problem with a version of R.